# add/remove Observer in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

I'm using code below to catch frame changes of collectionViewCell.

```
class MovieCardCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        awakeFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // configuring cell and views

        contentView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: .New, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>())
    }

    deinit {
        contentView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
    }

    override func updateViews() {
        // changing some views
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context:     UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let key = keyPath {
            switch (key) {
                case "frame":
                    updateViews()
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i still get error for UIView deallocated before observers being released.

I'm using the same mechanism for other views and other objects and it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` will get called when all nib files has been loaded successfully. Calling `awakeFromNib` yourself, will cause this method to get called twice, hence will register two observers.

A good practice is to define another method like `func commonInit()` and call `commonInit()` from both `init` methods and register the observer in `commonInit`